# Grouping result from subquery in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a a query which gets me result using sub query. I am trying to get distinct value for one of the column using group by and distinct by I am getting error

```
ORA-01791: not a SELECTed expression
```

My SQL query look like

```
select distinct myCol from (
  select dbCol as myCol from someTable where <someCondition>
  unionall
  <some other sql>
) group by myCol;
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Why are you selecting a distinct column and then grouping by it? If you select distinct, only one row of it will be returned, so there's nothing to group by.

Comment: Please post the code you're actually using and what you're trying to do.  What you've posted will cause many errors.  For example `union all` is two words, not one.

Comment: My suggestion is to take away the group by clause.

Comment: Perhaps, you have a `ORDER BY` clause accompanying a `DISTINCT`-ed select.. And the column in the `ORDER BY` is *not* in your `SELECT`. Just imagine, when you pick up distinct of something, how can you order it by other thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query should be fine, once you fix `unionall`.  I would write it as:

```
select myCol
from ((select dbCol as myCol
       from someTable
       where <someCondition>
      ) union all
      (<some other sql>)
     ) t
group by myCol;
```

Note that you do not need `distinct` with `group by`.  One or the other is fine if your `select` only has one column.  The `group by` has more functionality.